# How to get the value of text of autocomplete wrapper

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, vuejs2

I am using autocomplete library from [this](https://github.com/BosNaufal/vue2-autocomplete). It works fine without issues. As per the requirement, I need an option to click on search button by clicking will display all the results as per the text in the textbox (just like Facebook search box).  How do I get the text-entered in the textbox after clicking on search button? in the below code, which clicked on search, I want the text inserted in search box. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
 <autocomplete url="/autocomplete" anchor="label" :on-select="gotoMethod">
 </autocomplete>
 <button type="button" @click="search()" class="button ml-10">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using below solution. I would be happy to know if there is any other alternative for this?

```
<li>
    <autocomplete
       url="/autocomplete"
       anchor="label"
       :on-select="gotoUserProfile"
       :onBlur="setNameValue">
    </autocomplete>
</li>
```

I used `onBlur` and set the value

```
setNameValue: function (event) {
    this.name = event.srcElement.value;
}
```